# ADO.net query from coming from APP.config not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net, app-config

Below is my sql query written in APP.Config

```
<add key="query" value="Select *
     from POManage po 
     Where po.VendorID = @manufacturerid
     and po.order_date between @StartDate and @EndDate order by PONumber asc"/>
```

Here is my Program .cs code

```
 int manufacturerid = 32;     
 DateTime StartDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
 DateTime EndDate = DateTime.Now;
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
 cmd.Parameters.Add("@manufacturerid", SqlDbType.BigInt,manufacturerid);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartDate", StartDate);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EndDate", EndDate);
 cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
 SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
 ad.Fill(ds);
```

But it is showing error for @manufacturerid Must declare the scalar variable.

Similar issue is coming for StartDate and EndDate.

Comment: *DON'T* pass the dates as strings, that's guaranteed to cause conversion problems. Use `DateTime.Date` if you want to strip the time part and just pass the date values you want

Comment: the `app.config` is probably not the best place to store queries. I recommend a resource or settings file or configuration file instead.

Comment: Why is `po.order_date` not an actual `date` type (Why the conversion to type Date)? If you are storing a date then you need to use the Date type, that is what it is there for. Otherwise everything would just be string and there would be no such thing as types....

Comment: @Igor its requirement I cannot do any thing for that

Comment: Also `WHERE po.VendorID = @manufacturerid`, do not wrap the value in quotes unless `VendorID` is a string in which case the question why is it a string?

Comment: @Igor that's not the question at all. Quotes means that instead of the parameter, the OP is searching for a row whose `VendorID` field contains the string value `'@manufacturerId'`. No numeric column is going to contain that

Comment: Coverted '@ManufacturerId' to @ManufacturerId in query and VendorID datatype is bigint

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Please review updated question and i had Changed the query as you said but still same issue is coming. the actuall issue seems to be in Manufacturer id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

firstly, It's a very bad idea to keep the command query in the appconfig

You have already created a command with query. You need pass the command to Adapter. not query.

```
 int manufacturerid = 32;     
 StartDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
 EndDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
 cmd.Parameters.Add("@manufacturerid", SqlDbType.BigInt,manufacturerid);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartDate", StartDate);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EndDate", EndDate);
 cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
 SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
 ad.Fill(ds);
```

and change `Where po.VendorID = '@manufacturerid'`  to `Where po.VendorID = @manufacturerid` in your query

**update:**

```
        int manufacturerid = 32;
        var query = @"Select * from POManage po
            Where po.VendorID = @manufacturerid
            and CONVERT(DATE, po.order_date) between @StartDate and @EndDate 
            order by PONumber asc";
        var startDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
        var endDate = DateTime.Now;
        var connectionString = "your connection string";
        var dataTable = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con))
            {
                adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@manufacturerid", manufacturerid);
                adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartDate", startDate);
                adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EndDate", endDate);
                adapter.Fill(dataTable);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Ok i updated and now i m getting issue as The parameterized query '(@manufacturerid bigint,@StartDate nvarchar(10),@EndDate nvarcha' expects the parameter '@manufacturerid', which was not supplied.

Comment: Do I need to made changes in my query written in App.config?

Comment: what change i need to made in my query, query is running properly if i placed proper value and run it in sql server

Comment: @Xtremcool you aren't copying the *same* query. First, instead of using the `@manufacturerid` parameter you have a literal `'@manufacturerid'`. Second, you cast strings to dates without actually knowing what locale is used on the server. Just *don't* pass dates as strings. Calculate the dates you want on the client and pass the date values to the query

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the thing is initially it is not working for manufacturerid , If this issue is solved we can go forward for startdate and end date

Comment: Changed Where po.VendorID = '@manufacturerid' to Where po.VendorID = @manufacturerid still same issue is coming

Comment: yess, @Xtremcool you are right.  you dont need  "date to string" on c#  and after "string to date" on tsql

Comment: Please review updated question and i had Changed the query as you said but still same issue is coming. the actuall issue seems to be in Manufacturer id

Comment: The issue was only cmd.Parameters.Add("@manufacturerid", SqlDbType.BigInt,manufacturerid); to cmd.Parameters.Add("@manufacturerid",manufacturerid);